# how can i publish HTML and plain-text template used by mail notifications in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, laravel-artisan, vendor

when I run this command :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

To publishing the HTML and plain-text template used by mail notifications,this throws the following error :

> [UnexpectedValueException]
>        Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers]

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's not related to `vendor:publish`. The error is telling you that one of the `uses` clause in your route file `web.php (default)` is not recognisable, or not defined, or malformed. Make sure all `uses` is indeed pointing to defined `Controller@action`.

Comment: thank you for helping me. yes the problem was in my {web.php}  .